# Get objects from List of objects based on variable in object

Tags: java, list, collections, comparator

I have List of User object, I just want to get User objects from List based on variables in User object.

```
public class User {

    private int id;

    private String sex;

    private int age;

    private String country;

    /**
     * Getter and setter for all variables
     */
}
```

I have a model class like this. Now I have list of User objects.

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

I want to get the objects from users list if the user is Male.

```
List<User> ageList = new ArrayList<User>();
for(User object : users) {
    if(object.getSex().equals("Male")){
        ageList.add(object);
    }
}
```

I do not like the above approach. Is there any better way to get objects from List of objects based on variable in object..?

Is there any functions Java Collections ..? can we solve this using Java Comparator..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can use `Collections2.filter`:

```
Collection<User> males = Collections2.filter(users, new Predicate<User>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(User user) {
        return user.getSex().equals("Male");
    }
});
```

And with Java 8, you can do even better:

```
Collection<User> males = Collections2.filter(users, user -> user.getSex().equals("Male"));
```

Comment: The reason I don't like this notation is that it longer and adds libraries/methods which someone reading it later might not be familiar with. It is a shame Java doesn't have better support for this use case (Like just about every other popular language :P )

Comment: @Peter: I agree, Ruby is a zillion times better: `males = users.select {|user| user.sex == 'Male'}`

Comment: Even boring and very old SQL `select * from Users where sex = "Male"` I tend to like expressions which are both short and need less symbols.  Most programmers can understand and write simple SQL.

Comment: I was in confusion about which api to use, google collections or apache colletions.. Finally I selected google ..

Comment: if i were to get List<age> filtered out of the collection? how would i go about tweaking this.

Comment: is it possible to use this filter or just iterating over the group of objects in the list is the only plausible way?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with lambda functions and reflections.  However since Java doesn't support closures you will find that this approach is more error prone, requires more code and is slower.

If you want a fast way to do this you could main that a Map<Sec, List<User>> or MultiMap.

BTW: I would use an Enum for the Sex of the person.  You should be able to limit yourself to a few possibilities ;) You could do similarly with Country.

Comment: @Arul BTW, if all you wish is to retrieve Users based on their sex attribute and you do change it to be an Enum type instead of a String, you could then use an EnumMap which is quite quick, as it is based on an array

Comment: A few possibilities? Let's see...female, male, intersex, unknown, and other (and whatever other options I forgot)? :-)

Comment: @Chris, However you do it, the number is going to be small.

Comment: And then there's this: http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2010/11/26/disalienation/ :-)

Comment: @Chris, True, but that will make it hard to do searches on. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way in java8 with streams filter

```
List<User> males = users.stream().filter(u -> u.getSex().equals("Male")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple filters I like lambdaj onliners syntax:
http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures

```
List<User> ageList = filter(having(on(User.class).getSex(), equalTo("Male")), users);
```

For complex conditions it is better to create separate filter finction.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MultiValueMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html) from [Apache common collection](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) or simply `Map<String List<User>>` to split users at the beginning, if get users according to sex is all what you need.

As long as you want to get particular users from an unsorted collection, search through whole collection is a must. So there is no better way to retrieve it. However, you can hide this logic beneath the surface.

Apache common collections (and Guava as Chris Jester-Young mentioned) provide `CollectionUtils.select()`, all you need to do is implement the `Predicate`. (check the answer from Chris Jester-Young for better explanation)

Or, instead of using collection to pass users around, make it into an object like `Users` or `UserPack`. Then you can implement a method call `getMaleUsers()` to return all male users inside the object for you. This trick is quite useful if you need to manipulate particular objects a lot.