# Removing objects from list based on Id match from other list

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, arraylist

I have a list of objects `List<A>  list1`...
`A` has two members `id` and `name`... Now I have one more list `List<Integer> list2` containing only id's. 
..I need to remove all the `A` objects from `list1` whose id is not present in `list2` .

What I have tried so far:

```
void removeUnwanted(List<A> a, List<Integer> b) {
    for (A object : a) {
        if (!(b.contains(object.id))) {
            b.remove(object)
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with suggestion most efficient way to do this ??

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code!

Comment: I tried somthing like this :


removeUnwanted(List<A> a, List<Integer> b){

for(A object : a){

if(!(b.contains(object.id))){

b.remove(object)
}
}

Comment: not sure how to write code here in better format

Comment: I've edited your question!

Comment: Some related questions:
[Filtering a list of JavaBeans with Google Guava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636502/filtering-a-list-of-javabeans-with-google-guava) ... 
[Get objects from List of objects based on variable in object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242276/get-objects-from-list-of-objects-based-on-variable-in-object) ... 
[Filter unique objects from an ArrayList based on property value of the contained object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287842/filter-unique-objects-from-an-arraylist-based-on-property-value-of-the-contained)

Comment: There is a philosophical argument as to whether your method should even modify the input `List<A>`. Some people will say 
it's fine; others will say you should create and return a new unmodifiable list containing the desired elements.

Answer (score 7):

You should add the id's into a set for fast searching, then iterate over the list and remove the ids that are not in the id's set:

```
Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet<Integer>(list2);
Iterator<A> it = list1.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (!ids.contains(it.next().id)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using streams (Java8) one would write:

```
List<Obj>     objects = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> ids     = new LinkedList<>();

// fill objects and ids

Set<Integer>  idHash  = new HashSet<>(ids);

objects = new LinkedList<>(objects.stream()
                                      .filter(e -> idHash.contains(e.getID()))
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: While certainly a 1-liner, it seems O(n^2) to me, since the contains() is `O(n)`, and is done per element. Far from 'most efficient'.

Comment: @amit Would it be faster, if the IDs were stored in a hash set?

Comment: A HashSet offers O(1) (average) contains()

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in `O(n)` time (average case) and space by creating a [`HashMap<Integer,A>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) where the key is the ID, and the value is the `A` object.

Now, iterate the list `list2` and yield only values (`A` objects) that have a key matching some id in `list2`.

java-like Pseudo code:

```
Map<Integer,A> map = new HashMap<>();
for (A a : list1) map.put(a.id,a);
for (int id : list2) { 
   A a = map.get(id);
   //do something with a, maybe populate a new list
}
```

An alternative is sort both lists, and iterate in parallel, while discarding elements that has no matching ids. This gives O(nlogn) time (worst case) and O(1) space:

high level pseudo code:

```
sort(list1) //according to id
sort(list2)
iter1 = 0
iter2 = 0
while (iter1<list1.size() && iter2<list2.size()) { 
   int id = list1.get(iter1).id
   if (id < list2.get(iter2)) { //discard and advance the smaller one
       list1.remove(iter1) //can be done efficiently if the list is linked list

   } else if (id == list2.get(iter2)) { //advance both, element should remain in list1
      iter1++; iter2++;
   } else { //advance iter2
      iter2++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeUnwanted(List<A> a, List<Integer> b) {
    boolean result = false;
    for (A object : a) {
        for (int i : b) {
            if ((i == (object.id))) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        if (result == false) {
            a.remove(object);
        }
        result = false;
    }
}
```